# How to make wysiwyg using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, wysiwyg

I want to make wysiwyg like 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP3p6.png]

Do you know how to make it?

Comment: Youre trying to make a rich editor or something?  I would possibly look at other implementations on Github, or design 1 of those buttons with a dynamic click, icon, and tooltip and then  link them together.

Comment: Please check the question guidelines to improve your changes of getting quality answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Zefyr looks pretty promising https://github.com/memspace/zefyr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Angular Quill dart component.

See [demo](https://adamlofts.github.io/angular_quill_example/build/web/index.html) and [source](https://pub.dev/packages/angular_quill).

Or you can choose [yabwe](https://pub.dev/packages/yabwe).

https://pub.dev/packages?q=wysiwyg

Answer (score 2):

These are some options right now if you need a WYSIWYG editor for Flutter and don't mind that they are wrapping Javascript:

1. [Flutter Quill](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) (based on [Quill](https://quilljs.com) which is not active).
2. [Flutter Summernote](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_summernote) (based on [Summernote](https://summernote.org))
3. [Flutter HTML Editor Enhanced](https://github.com/tneotia/html-editor-enhanced)  (also based on Summernote)

If you prefer another Javascript WYSIWYG library take a look at wrapping your own using the js package: https://pub.dev/packages/js

Comment: Super Editor seems to be a new option. Been using quill so far. The delta format is great.

Comment: Summernote renders html in a webview. Not great...

Answer (score 1):

this package is much better used like summernote

[Summernote package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_summernote)