# Html wysiwyg editor in flutter?

Tags: html, flutter, editor, wysiwyg, summernote

is there any way to use summernote or wysiwyg editor in Flutter textfield editor?

I used flutter_html_editor, Zefyr, html_editor and flutter_summernote packages, but these dont worked well and they returned null value in the following code:

```
    final _etEditor = await keyEditor.currentState.getText();
```

I got the following error:

```
E/flutter ( 6639): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'getText' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 6639): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 6639): Tried calling: getText()
```

I want that the textfield become like the attached image. How to fix it?

Can I implement a package like these, or is there any solution to make summernote or wysiwyg textfield editor which can convert html tags in Flutter?

[image]

thanks

Comment: Could you provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we could check in what part you are getting the error? Also, could you verify if [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59566476/how-to-make-wysiwyg-using-flutter) could help you?

Answer (score 2):

you can try my package [html_editor_enhanced](https://github.com/tneotia/html-editor-enhanced) which does not have the `getText()` error and uses fully native controls with plenty of customization. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I get issue when i use both flutter_html, html_editor. image_picker: ^0.6.4
  flutter_html: ^2.0.0
  html_editor: ^1.0.1  Because every version of html_editor depends on webview_flutter ^0.3.21 and flutter_html 2.0.0 depends on webview_flutter ^2.0.4, html_editor is incompatible with flutter_html 2.0.0.
And because no versions of flutter_html match >2.0.0 <3.0.0, html_editor is incompatible with flutter_html ^2.0.0.
So, because shipnet_drydock depends on both flutter_html ^2.0.0 and html_editor ^1.0.1, version solving failed.

Comment: Dont use html_editor, use html_editor_enhanced: ^2.1.1 :)

Comment: @TanayNeotia: Experienced one weird issue with your package html_editor_enhanced on flutter web. When i choose to insert table, a dialog appears which is scrollable to select the rows and columns. But if i provide the 

otherOptions: OtherOptions(height: 1000), height can be any value, then scrolling does not work inside insert table dialog. Any solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

Using flutter_summernote

getText() always throw error, but I have a work around

```js
GlobalKey < FlutterSummernoteState > _keyEditor = GlobalKey();
String globalText = "";

FlutterSummernote(
  //showBottomToolbar: _keyboardVisible,
  hasAttachment: true,
  value: globalText,
  hint: globalText == null ? "Your text here..." : "",
  key: _keyEditor,
  returnContent: (_) {
    print("text from return Context $_");
    globalText = _;
  }),
```